# Does SYSDATE change affects table stats in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

One of our dbas said that after changing system date in Oracle (we need to do this in order to test our software) we need to collect all the statistics for our tables - is this true? If yes, then why? I couldn't firn anything in Oracle docs. One thing that comes to my mind is that the job which automatically collects stats may hung on waiting for next run date that was jumped off.

Any other ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "changing system date in Oracle"? Are you going to modify the system date on OS level? Do you want to "move" time forward or backwards? Some tables like `DBA_OBJECTS` and `DBA_TABLES` contain dates like `CREATED` or `LAST_ANALYZED`, these probably should not contain any "future" time. BTW: you can also "adjust" system time on Oracle DB to OS system time by configuring the Listener. So you can have the "current" time on OS level but having for example +6 hours on Oracle level. This can be handy if you host some application for some country residing in a different time zone.

Comment: Yes, that's a neat trick; we used to use that for testing housekeeping routines. It was more useful in the past when you could go pretty much as far back or forward as you want; in 11g you're limited to 24 hours. Which is reasonable, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, we are changing system time. We are jumping forward in order to test yearly processes, like financial year closure. We are not getting back, we simply "speed up" the time. Does it mean that statistics have some kind of expiry date, so we have to collect them after such a jump (the data and indexes does not change)?

Comment: @WojtusJ Statistics depend on so-called segment space monitoring. If more that 10% of tables' segment gets modified, the table is marked as *stale* and will be analyzed during next stats. gather job. On the other hand Oracle has ~internal limitation~ for flashback queries against `UNDO` tablespace. Oracle will not allow you to see deleted data if it was deleted more that 5 days ago. Personally would just shutdown database, change the system (OS) time and then start the DB again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the system date probably does not require regathering statistics.  The table statistics do not contain the actual SYSDATE.  Even when the execution plan is extremely sensitive to the SYSDATE, Oracle appears to handle the date change very well.

However, it wouldn't surprise me too much if there was some weird error somewhere related to changing the date.  But you should ask the DBA for specific details, including an Oracle Support bug number.

Below is an example of the optimizer handling a change to the operating system date perfectly.

**1:** Remove all current cached SQL, just in case.

```
alter system flush shared_pool;
```

**2:** Create a table with a skewed column.  There are many values for today but only a few for tomorrow.

```
drop table test1;
create table test1(a date, b varchar2(100));
create index test1_idx on test1(a);
insert into test1 select trunc(sysdate), 'common value' from dual
  connect by level <= 100000;
insert into test1 select trunc(sysdate)+1, 'rare value' from dual
  connect by level <= 10;
--Workload to generate histograms.
select max(b) from test1 where a = trunc(sysdate);  
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'TEST1');
end;
/
```

**3:** Selecting the common data, from today, correctly uses a full table scan.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') current_date from dual;

CURRENT_DATE
------------
2014-01-05

explain plan for select b from test1 where a = trunc(sysdate);
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => '-cost -bytes -predicate'));

Plan hash value: 4122059633

------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name  | Rows  | Time     |
------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |       |   100K| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST1 |   100K| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------
```

**4:** Selecting the rare data, from tomorrow, correctly use an index range scan.

```
explain plan for select b from test1 where a = trunc(sysdate)+1;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => '-cost -bytes -predicate'));

Plan hash value: 1226949

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name      | Rows  | Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |           |    10 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TEST1     |    10 | 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | TEST1_IDX |    10 | 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**5:** Change the operating system clock to tomorrow.  SYSDATE is instantly updated.

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') current_date from dual;

CURRENT_DATE
------------
2014-01-06
```

**6:** Re-run step #3.  This query previously returned a large amount of data, now it returns only a small amount of data.  The plan should and does change from a full table scan to an index range scan.

```
explain plan for select b from test1 where a = trunc(sysdate);
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => '-cost -bytes -predicate'));

Plan hash value: 1226949

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name      | Rows  | Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |           |    10 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TEST1     |    10 | 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | TEST1_IDX |    10 | 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```